# Used to have or had?

Tags: meaning-in-context, past-tense, phrase-choice, construction, past-habitual

What is the difference between:

I didn't use to have a phone

AND

I didn't have a phone

Maybe the first option is not correct at all? I will be grateful for explanation :).

Comment: So far as I'm concerned, [***nobody knows***](https://www.quora.com/Which-one-is-correct-didnt-used-to-or-didnt-use-to#:~:text=The%20negative%20of%20used%20to,shops%20as%20it%20is%20nowadays.) whether it should be *didn't **use** to* or *didn't **used** to* (impossible to distinguish in speech, which imho is the only "real" language). But even though it's a bit *unlikely* today, I don't think anyone could seriously argue with the syntax of *I **usen't** to have a phone.*

Comment: ..actually, having read all the posts in my above link, I find I'm now convinced by the argument that *I didn't **use** to care* is an ***infinitive*** - same as *I didn't **care*** (not *I didn't **cared***). Particularly when I consider the alternative phrasing ***I never cared*** rather than ***...didn't [use to] care***.

Comment: I think "speech is the only real languge" is a bit too much.  Indeed one key feature of language is that it is medium independent. The human brain can receive language by sound, by written symbols, by signs, by touch(braille) This is a remarkable, yet rarely remarked on, property of human language

Comment: The OP didn't ask about the spelling of "didn't use to".  The question is about "didn't use to" versus "didn't have".

Comment: @rjpond: Actually, I think the negation is irrelevant to OP's question, which is really about the difference between *I **had** a phone* and *I **used to have** a phone.*

Answer (score 1):

*I used to* refers to a situation in the past that lasted for some time. So -

*I didn't have a phone* (at a particular point in time).

*I didn't use to* or *I used not to have a phone* = There was a period of time before I acquired one.

Comment: Thank you!
So, in the sentence: When I was young, I...... a phone, didn't have is better and didn't use to would have to be further explained that now i have a phone?

Comment: That isn't what I meant. Cactustictacs' answer explains it in more detail. _When I was young_ is a period of time, not a particular point, so you can say _I didn't use to have a phone then_, which implies that now you do have one. You could say _I couldn't let you know that I was going to be late, because I didn't have a phone_ (referring to a particular day).

Comment: Thank you, that explains everything! Sorry for problems <3

Answer (score 1):

*Used to* implies some change has taken place - in the past, some action was done regularly ("I used to ride my bike to school") or some state was true ("this used to be more fun"), but at some point that changed (I stopped riding my bike, or I don't go to school anymore, and the fun thing became less fun). And the negative version says that it *wasn't* the case, but implies that at some point it became true.

So *I didn't use to have a phone* is saying that in the past you didn't have one, but it gives the impression that now you do - that situation changed. *I didn't have a phone* is just talking about one time (or specific period of time) in the past, it isn't saying anything about any other time. You can add other words to imply something changed (like *I didn't have a phone **then*** seems to contrast with **now**), but *didn't use to* has that sense built in.

I started this with "used to is used to" and had to stop because it was going to look very confusing...

Comment: Thank you so much <3

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the “didn’t use” option in the case where you now have a phone, but didn’t use to. The other option doesn’t seem to be clear on this.

As to the whether it should be “use” or “used”, I’d say “use” in your specific case.

There does seem to be some confusion around it, but I’d basically align it with the following examples:

> I used the soap.

> I did use the soap.

> I didn’t use the soap.

So you’d have:

> I used to have a phone.

> I did use to have a phone.

> I didn’t use to have a phone.

Comment: Thank you! So, in the sentence: When I was young, I...... a phone, didn't have is better and didn't use to would have to be further explained that now i have a phone?

Comment: Yes, I would agree with that. :)